# HTML intellisense does not work in VS code

Tags: autocomplete, intellisense, vscode-extensions

I am writing a Flask app and notice that HTML intellisense does not work now. As you can see in the screenshot, the input shows no autocomplete options. The form tag also does not work. I type that all manually.

[image]

I've tried lots of extensions, but none of them work. The "html.autoClosingTags" has been set true.

Could someone help with that?